# How can I overwrite my array with a new one using express mongodb or mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I replace the entire array with another array using express and mongoose?

sample data:

```
{
"_id": 1,
"item": "Car",
"features": [
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "wheels": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "mirrors": true
  }
 ]
}
```

say I re-ordered my features array to this:

```
"features": [
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "mirrors": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "wheels": true
  }
]
```

what I did is:

```
router.patch('/items/:item_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const item = await Item.update(
       { _id: req.params.item_id }, 
       { $set: { features: [req.body] } }
    )
    
    res.send(item)

  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e)
  }
})
```

req.body is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "mirrors": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "wheels": true
  }
]
```

I pass the whole array using req.body to overwrite the old one but doesn't return what I expected

Comment: I guess you want `req.body` and not `[req.body]`. Otherwise you are creating an array with another array as one element in it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update):

> Returns: «Query»
>
> Updates one document in the database without
> returning it.

So `Model.update(...)` does not acutally return the updated document.

If you need to retrieve the updated document you should use `findOneAndUpdate` along with the [option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) `{new:true}`:

```
router.patch('/items/:item_id', auth, async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const updatedDoc = await Item.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.item_id }, 
            { $set: { features: req.body} }, 
            { new: true }
        );

        res.send(updatedDoc)

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: for some weird reason, it adds an item in my array {"_id": "5ef08d2e4af50725d6595cf8"}

Comment: forgive me, looks like I have a duplicate route *facepalm*. thanks for your replies guys!

Comment: Happy to help, you can accept the answer if you like :)